# Python Inheritance, delete inheritance, but result didn't change

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, python-internals

Here is an example in *A Byte of Python*. It is about Inheritance.

But when I delete the *(SchoolMember)*, everything is ok, the result didn't change. So, what the use of Inheritance. What's the difference between use and not use inheritance.

```
class SchoolMember:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('(Initialized SchoolMember: {})'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        print('Name:"{}" Age:"{}"'.format(self.name, self.age), end=" ")


class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.salary = salary
        print('(Initialized Teacher: {})'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print('Salary: "{:d}"'.format(self.salary))


class Student(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self, name, age, marks):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.marks = marks
        print('(Initialized Student: {})'.format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print('Marks: "{:d}"'.format(self.marks))

t = Teacher('Mrs. Shrividya', 40, 30000)
s = Student('Swaroop', 25, 75)

print()

members = [t, s]
for member in members:
    # Works for both Teachers and Students
    member.tell()
```

Comment: You probably just didn't remove the inheritance but made some changes, add the changes you did as well to your question.

Comment: I didn't change anything else. But I'm thinking is that because every class has a *tell* method, so it's ok to remove the interiance cause it didn't be used.

Comment: Are you still in the interpreter session where you defined `SchoolMember`? If so, the two subclasses are still keeping references to it, so it hasn't been deleted yet, it's just not available to your interpreter session anymore.

Comment: Your Subclasses don't have `self.name` defined, so removing `SchoolMember` won't work. You should try to understand the benefits of inheritance better. With inheritance, you wouldn't need to define `tell` in every class

Comment: Yes, Ithink user1767754 is right and  I now understand the Inheritance more, and thank for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

> when I delete the (SchoolMember), everything is ok, the result didn't
> change.

Deleting only *SchoolMember* removes the variable name.  The *Teacher* and *Student* classes still refer to the original class in their _*bases*_ attribute.

Try this instead:

```
del SchoolMember.__init__
del SchoolMember.tell
```

That will empty out the parent class by removing the inherited methods.

> So, what the use of Inheritance

The purpose of inheritance is code reuse.  In your example, it allows the code in *SchoolMember* to be used in two other classes, *Teacher* and *Student*.